# ERROR: "email" is not a known variable

Tags: sql, postgresql, heroku, authentication

I have created a stored procedure for my login feature and it works fine however when I deployed it to heroku it gave me the error.

This is my stored procedure in sql:

```
    create or replace function login(in par_email  text, in par_password text) returns text as
$$
  declare
    loc_eml text;
    loc_pwd text;
    loc_res text;
  begin
     select into loc_eml, loc_pwd, email, password from account
       where email = par_email and password = par_password;

     if loc_eml isnull AND loc_pwd isnull then
       loc_res = 'Error';
     else
       loc_res = 'ok';
     end if;
     return loc_res;
  end;
$$
 language 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;
```

Comment: that's what confuses me because i do have an email column in the account table that i made

Comment: Is email a reserved word?

Comment: ah, right look at `select into loc_eml, loc_pwd, email, password` line - the order of is bad

Comment: @yuyu: Please add table structure of account table.

Comment: CREATE TABLE "account"(
 "acc_id" Varchar NOT NULL,
 "username" Varchar,
 "email" Varchar,
 "password" Varchar
)
;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query inside procedure should be like:

```
select email, password into loc_eml, loc_pwd
from account
where email = par_email and password = par_password;
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
SELECT email, password INTO loc_eml, loc_pwd FROM account ...
```